# Parallax navigation menu to change colors on specific slides

Tags: jquery, css

I'm building a parallax website and I wanted my parent navigation and its child to change color on specific slides so as to be visible. What code should I use in jQuery to achieve this?

This is my CSS, markup and code:

```
.navigation{
    font-family:thin lines and curves;
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    z-index:51;
    top:50%;
    left:6%;
}

.navigation li{
    font-family:thin lines and curves;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    padding:0 10px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation li:hover,
.active{
    font-family:thin lines and curves;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.navigation2{
    font-family:thin lines and curves;                                   /*EC2127 - red color tone of logo*/
    position:fixed;
    text-align:right;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    top:50%; 
    left:88%;
    z-index:51;
    }
.navigation2 li{
    font-family:thin lines and curves;
    color:#fff;
    display:block;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    padding:0 10px;
    line-height:30px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
}
.navigation2 li:hover,.active{
    font-family:thin lines and curves;
    cursor:pointer;
    text-decoration:underline;







<ul class="navigation">
    <li data-slide="1"><img class="geshalogo" src="images/geshalogo.png"></li>
        <li data-slide="2">estate
                <ul class="navigation2">
                <li data-slide="2">land</li>
                <li data-slide="3">varietal</li>
                <li data-slide="4">people</li>
                <li data-slide="6">practices</li>
                <li data-slide="9">future offerings</li>
                </ul>
        </li>
        <li data-slide="10">about</li>
        <li data-slide="13">location</li>
        <li data-slide="14">contact</li>
    </ul>







jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


    //initialise Stellar.js
    $(window).stellar();

    //Cache some variables

    var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
    var link = $('.navigation2').find('li'); // informs to cache a second set of navigation and sets it to play
    slide = $('.slide');
    button = $('.button');
    mywindow = $(window);
    htmlbody = $('html,body');


    //Setup waypoints plugin

    slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

        //cache the variable of the data-slide attribute associated with each slide

        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

        //If the user scrolls up change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and 
        //remove the active class from the previous navigation link

        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
        }
                // else If the user scrolls down change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and 
        //remove the active class from the next navigation link

        else {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
        }
        // same as the aboove for the second set of navigations

        if (direction === 'down') {
           $('.navigation2 li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
        }
        else {
           $('.navigation2 li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
       }

    });

    //waypoints doesnt detect the first slide when user scrolls back up to the top so we add this little bit of code, that removes the class 
    //from navigation link slide 2 and adds it to navigation link slide 1.

    mywindow.scroll(function () {
        if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
            $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    mywindow.scroll(function () {
        if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
            $('.navigation2 li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
            $('.navigation2 li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
        }
    });

    //Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
    //easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.

    function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
        htmlbody.animate({
            scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
        }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
    }

    //When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function

    links.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);
    });

    //When the user clicks on the button, get the get the data-slide attribute value of the button and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function

    button.click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
        goToByScroll(dataslide);

    });

    $('.navigation2').hide(); //Hide children by default

    $('.navigation').children().click(function(){
    $(this).siblings().children('.navigation2').hide();
    $(this).children('.navigation2').slideToggle(2000, 'easeInOutQuint');     
    }).children('.navigation2').click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
    });


    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the way your code is written there is only one thing to do for applying different colors based on the current active slide.

First declare an array of objects that represent each slide's visual settings that you'll need:

```
var slideSettings = [
   { 'links': '#AAA', 'background': '#FFF', 'image': 'http://url-to-an-image1.png' },
   { 'links': '#BBB', 'background': '#FFF', 'image': 'http://url-to-an-image2.png' }
   // add more colors here ...
];
```

After that whenever the user changes the current slide (scrolls up or down) you are going to apply the current slide settings to the navigation elements that need to be changed.

```
// ... whenever the user changes the current slide
$('.navigation li').css('color', slideSettings[dataslide].links);
$('.navigation li').css('background-color', slideSettings[dataslide].background);
$('.navigation li img').attr('src', slideSettings[dataslide].image);
// ... continue with the rest ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. That only seems to change the color of my nav and dont change it back, I was thinking more of an if function where if dataslide has a certain value (example on slides 4,6 and 10) then nav color is #ddd else nav color is #fff. So that based on a specific slide the color will change.... can I achieve that?

Comment: You are welcome! If I understand you well, the colors will be set by you right? If yes then whenever the "dataslide" variable changes you can update the colors of the elements that you want. So the above method should work for you elegantly.

Comment: It works fine, but how about following the waypoint and changing back or in reverse order of the set colors? When user slides back up I want it to change back to the assigned colors. Also if you have noticed one of the links is an image and I have another one with a different color set. How can I change that as well? Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it very much!

Comment: In the "navColors" array you can store objects with multiple values (link & background colors, images, other css values - whatever you need to be changed in each slide). Each array object should be used in a specific slide, you'll decide that. *** You will also need to add in the "navColors" array the initial color and image settings and then when you scroll up, these settings will change back as you want. *** When the user scolls up the dataslide variable must be decreased (I'm stating this in case you haven't done it already).

Comment: Just changed the "navColors" array name to "slideSettings" so it would be more clear, what data contains.

Comment: Thanks again for your help!! I cant tell you how much I appreciate it. What do you mean by "dataslide variable must be decreased"? How can I do that?

Comment: Would this be the correct code:  
`if (direction === 'up') {
$('.navigation li[data-slide="' - dataslide - '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
}
else {
$('.navigation li[data-slide="' - dataslide - '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');`

Comment: Seems to me like it would work, but I will suggest you to break down all these macros because they are not so easy to read. And when a project is full of these it will be more difficult for a developer to maintain the code.